# Covering Airing Vents in Floor

Tags: flooring

I have been asked to help fix a home up for someone, it needs work on flooring, drywall, doors, exterior etc. My question is, the central heat/AC is no good and to cool and heat the home the homeowners use window units. With that said, all the floor vents are damaged or just a hole in the floor. The open holes seems to have caused them a rodent problem. Would there be a issue with removing the damaged ductwork and covering up the holes for the vents permanetly?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. This may be too opinion-based for our format, but just in case: what type of floors are there? And, where is the home located?

Answer (score 1):

Your heating/ac system was designed to distribute “conditioned” air (heated or cooled) throughout your house. Covering a few registers will cause air to be redirected randomly to other parts of your house. This causes over-heating in some rooms and over-cooling in other rooms, depending on what the thermostat is calling for.

Yes, you can remove the existing damaged ducts and reinstall a new balanced system and cover the registers that are in the wrong location. However, the new ducts will need to be sized properly. I’d have a reputable heating and air conditioner contractor layout a new system. If they can’t, I’d contact a mechanical engineer (not civil engineer).

We’ve done this many times and we always search out and find where the rodents are entering the house and the system. As @Ed Beal said, rodents will tend to return to a warm environment.

Comment: According to the OP, it looks like they're not replacing the central HVAC at all, so this is pretty irrelevant. Seems to be a _weird_ way to go, but it seems that was the plan. (Yes, I know this is an old Q&A...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to put in a new HVAC system, the contractor you hire can answer this question. Floor registers are rarely used and if they are they are usually 2-1/2" or 4"wide and are along the walls. If there is a rodent problem it was not caused by the floor register openings.

Comment: I disagree, if they found there way in through the damaged duct work critters are always looking for a warm place in winter.

Comment: It appears that the home owner is _not_ replacing the HVAC, but using "window units". I've seen window AC units, but not heaters, except in hotels, so I'm not sure what they're using, but that's what the OP said...